# Is it possible to dogear PDF pages in Adobe Reader?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I find it very tedious to scroll to the page I am currently reading whenever I open a PDF document. Is there a way for example to dogear page 20 and have the document open at that very page the next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a way to have the document open at that very page the next time?

1. Menu "Edit" > "Preferences" (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>).
2. In the section "Categories" click "Documents".
3. In the section "Open Settings" enable (check) "Restore last view settings when reopening documents".
4. Click OK.

   [image]

Comment: This is a correct answer. A few things to keep in mind: it may fail when the document is read-only. Also, be aware that closing Acrobat (Reader) will take longer, because the document's information has to be written back.